# My DNN website works in Chrome in my PC, but in another PC it does not. And it does not work in any other browser

Tags: google-chrome, dotnetnuke

Well, it's really that. I have a website, https://www.fagakademiet.no, developed with DotNetNuke and we recently upgraded to V7.
Everything works fine in my PC using Chrome, but some people complain that it does not work in their PC's using also Chrome. When they login, the admin toolbar does not work.
It also doesn't work in IE, Opera, Firefox, etc.
Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

Often times issues like this are related to browser caching of the resources (JS,CSS,etc)

You might see if a Hard Refresh works for the users.

Also you might check the host settings to see if you have the client dependancy framework and resource minification enabled. Try disabling that if you do and see if that helps.